# Is a converging gaussian beam just another gaussian beam with a much larger Rayleigh length?

Tags: optics

This link seems to imply it, but I'm confused. Also, I don't intuitively see how the general shape of the gaussian remains the same. I'd expect it to be some kind of surposition between a normal gaussian and converging lines, like a $e^{-x} * sin$ function. https://www.ophiropt.com/blog/laser-measurement/focusing-a-gaussian-laser-beamwhich-formula-to-use/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all (theoretical) Gaussian beams are the same, no matter whether they are collimated or converging. There is always a waist (though it may not be in the portion of the beam that actually exists.)

A sharply converging Gaussian beam has a short Rayleigh length.

There is no such thing as a perfectly collimated Gaussian beam, only a beam with a very long Rayleigh length, since in reality the Rayleigh length cannot be infinite.